# php Mysql Order by Last Name Not Working

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query which works correctly in phpMyadmin, however doesn't when I echo it out on a page:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE MEMBER_TYPE Like 'LFM' ORDER BY LAST_NAME ASC ";

} 

$query = mysqli_query($link, $query);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){...`
```

For unknown reasons it simply will not sort the results by the last name column from within the table. Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob here. Not sure if I am using case-sensitive collation or not. Just trying to figure out if I am or not.

Comment: Collation in phpmyadmin is latin1_swedish_ci for everything. The 'LAST_NAME' column is varchar(255). 

I'm using php and mysqli to echo out the results into a simple table. Everything is structured perfectly but for the life of me it simply won't honor the ORDER BY line.

Comment: It won't even honor the order by id:
 
$query = "SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE MEMBER_TYPE Like 'LFM' ORDER BY ID ASC ";

Comment: In which case (and not that it's directly relevant) `LIKE` is identical to `=` in this context.

Comment: Yes about to say that what @Strawberry already mentioned. It should be a equality comparison. Moreover, how you know that it's not sorting? can you post the resultant data? and your current output?

Comment: Using the ID instead of LAST_NAME seems to work: $query = "SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE MEMBER_TYPE = 'LFM' ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT 5";

Results: 
68         
144         
161         
186         
189

Comment: Now I'm really confused. This query works correctly: $query = "SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE MEMBER_TYPE = 'LFM' ORDER BY LAST_NAME ASC";

ONLY when I remove the first name from the output. When I include the first name (a completely different variable and irrelevant to the query) into the table results it organizes by the $FIRST_NAME variable in spite of explicitly asking to Order by the LAST_NAME. The first name appears first in the table if that helps.

Comment: For fun I decided to display the last name first in the table and voila. It's ordering by last name ASC. What I can only assume this means is that this is a result of a default value setting in data tables having seniority where ordering is concerned (for the very first column) - or atleast that's my only logical conclusion...